# Reflecting (flipping) an image horizontally in C using 'temp' array

Tags: c

I am trying to reflect(filp horizontally) an image and I can't quite seem figure out why the image does not reflect and stays in original condition. I've tried many different methods (adding `-1` to `[width - j]` or assigning the `tempArray` as `RGBTRIPLE tempArray;`and dividing `width` with `/2` as the loop condition.

No errors being thrown, and I've followed the solutions from Stackoverflow and it seems like I am not quite getting there, any advices?

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE tempArray[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            tempArray[i][j] = image[i][j];
            image[i][j] = image[i][width - j];
            image[i][width - j] = tempArray[i][j];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)` You want to iterate 1/2 width times (although you say you tried this and it didn't work).

Comment: `tempArray` is totally unnecessary. You are flipping two elements at a time, and need one temporary variable only.

Comment: First off, you don't have any need for yet another 2-d array. A simple `int` will suffice to hold the swap value.

Comment: You swapped pixels in each row and then swapped them back.

Comment: Also, you go past the end of the array when `j == 0` at `image[i][width - j];`

Comment: Did you mean `[width - 1 - j]`?

Comment: @Weather Vane why do we subtract 1? could you elaborate on that please? trying to draw the mental picture

Comment: If you draw a line of five pixels, numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, on a piece of paper and go through how to reverse them, you will see how to do it.

Comment: Because as Johnny wrote, `[width - 0]` is off the map. the index of the r.h. pixel is `[width - 1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have 2 issues. First, since you iterate over the entire row, you end up swapping each item 2x. And that leaves just the original array.

Second, you access one past the end of the array with `image[i][width - j]` when `j == 0`. Valid indexes for an array are `0...(length-1)`.

Another, minor issue is that you don't need an array for the temp value.

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, int image[height][width])
{
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width / 2; j++)
        {
            temp = image[i][j];
            image[i][j] = image[i][width - j - 1];
            image[i][width - j - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Tested: https://ideone.com/EAALtI

Comment: Thanks so much Johnny!